# Transform first two columns of the pandas dataframe into rows and columns of a new dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a following dataframe:

```
In [1]: df.head()
Out[1]: 
     A    B     C
0    2.0  0.01  0.15748
1    2.0  0.02  0.01188
2    2.0  0.03  0.09856
3    2.0  0.04  0.04584
4    2.0  0.05  0.08280
```

Now, I want to create a new dataframe `df2` such that the values in column `A` would be its index values and values in the column `B` would be its column values and the values in the cell (A, B) would be the corresponding C value. Is there any simple way to do this?

Comment: I think you need `pivot`, if not, please add expected output to question. Thanks.

Comment: This solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome!